# No plugin found for prefix 'javafx' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, openjfx

```
No plugin found for prefix 'javafx' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\silas\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'javafx' in the current project and in the plugin groups
```

This is how I added the plugin to my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
                    <mainClass>your.package.with.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you actually want to use the plugin from `com.zenjava` or are you trying to apply the `org.openjfx` plugin: https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin

Comment: I am trying to build the native bundled installer for my JavaFX app.